# SQL: Filtering data with 2 matched conditions from 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

[image: test_result]

How do I get the student name who only failed at math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
from mytable 
where subject = 'math' and result = 'fail' AND name NOT IN (
   select name from mytable where subject != 'math' AND result = 'fail'
)
```